# Unix script to delete multiple files if it contains single line

Tags: shell

```
#!/bin/bash
LINECOUNT=wc -l 111.txt | cut -f8 -d' '
if [[ $LINECOUNT == 1 ]]; then rm -f 111.txt fi
```

What do I do for multiple files? Please advise.

Answer (score 2):

You need a `for` loop to iterate over the desired files:

```
for f in *.txt; do   # All file ending in '.txt' in the current directory
    LINECOUNT=$( wc -l < "$f" )
    if [[ $LINECOUNT == 1 ]]; then
        rm "$f"
    fi
done
```